# How do you set xpath in lxml to get tables into flat file format?

Tags: python, html, xpath, html-table, lxml

I'm trying to extract data out of a table string shown below and achieve the output as show below but I'm not sure how to set the xpath in lxml to do it. So far I'm able to extract only serial number and link using "//a" in xpath.

```
Region     | Link          | serial number | Description            | model
East Coast | /order/122342 | 122342        | CTO laptop series N123 | N123
West Coast | /order/122343 | 122342        | CTO laptop series Z123 | Z123
```

Below is my code and output:

```
import re
import lxml.html as html
import lxml.etree as etree

x = """
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <h2>East Coast</h2>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>serial number</th>
                <th>description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="/order/122342" target="_blank">122342</a></td>
                <td>CTO laptop series N123</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</tr>
<tr>
    <h2>West Coast</h2>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>serial number</th>
                <th>description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="/order/122343" target="_blank">122343</a></td>
            <td>CTO laptop series Z123</td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</tr>
<tr><h2>None</h2></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
"""

xt = etree.fromstring(x, parser=html.HTMLParser(recover=True, remove_comments=True))
print xt.xpath("//table//h2/text()")
print xt.xpath("//table//tr//td//text()")
print xt.xpath("//table//tr//td//a/@href")
print xt.xpath("//table//tr//td//a//text()")
```

**My Output:**

```
['East Coast', 'West Coast']
['122342', 'CTO laptop series N123', '122343', 'CTO laptop series Z123']
['/order/122342', '/order/122343']
['122342', '122343']
```

Comment: Your desired output has `Region`, `Link` and `model` headers, but those don't appear anywhere in your html code, so I don't know how you could possibly get them.

Comment: Also, why do you have tables nested inside another table?  That's a terrible way to do it.

Comment: This sample is based off a real State of California website. Unfortunately that's how sloppy it is. the regions are right up top the tables in the tags <h2>

Comment: Assuming that the td's without links in them are always the ones holding description, they should be pretty easy to get at: xpath('//td[not(a)]')

Comment: As for re'ing for the model I think it depends on what sort or descriptions you're going to see. Assuming it's always the last word in the decription: `model = re.search('[^ ]+$', desc)`

Comment: @brokkr what would be the best way to get header <h2> before each table?